# CSS: Positioning of individual images

Tags: php, css

I am building a comics website, but am having trouble aligning the images the way I want.

I'm going for this:

- I'm trying to get the comics in a row like this (blue)

[image]

But all the images are coming out on top of each other:

[image]

I thought my CSS was correct...

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }


 body {
background: gray;
text-align: center;
 }

 #wrapper {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
background: white;
 }


 #comics {
/*top, right, bottom, left*/
margin: 50px 100px 50px 100px;
 }

 .comicBG {
position: absolute;
border: 1px dotted black;
background: #99FF33;
padding: 25px;
  }
```

**PHP:**

```
 echo   '<td>';
 echo   '<span class="comicBG"><a href="./templates/viewcomic.php?id=' . $row['imgid'] .  '">
 <img src="' . $thumbpath.$row['imgthumb'] . '"/></a>' . 
 '<br /><a href="./templates/viewcomic.php?id=' . $row['imgid'] .  '">' .     $row['imgtitle'] . '</a></span>';
 echo   '</td>';
```

Does anyone know the best way to position individual data elements (like the images)?
Should I be using a table, or a list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use an unordeder list. And you see all the images at the same place because you've set their position to absolute and you haven't set any coordinates.

You can remove position:absolute and the images should be in rows. And if you use an unorderer list, you can float the li's to the left.

Comment: float:left worked!

but, why would you use an unordered list over a table? Do I still have control over total images in a row? (For example, I don't want all 6 images on a page in a single row.. or it will run off the page)

Comment: Semantically, a table is for tabular data. You just have a list of images. If the wrap has a width and the images (or li's) are floated, they'll build a new row when there's no room for them in one row.

Comment: Thanks Mario. But the UL defaults to 2 li's per row. I thought that was only because the parent element's width was too small, so I enlarged it.. and it was still set to 2 li's per row. Can I manually change when it wraps?

Comment: If there are only two li's per row, it's because there's no room for more. This can happen because of the wrapper's width or the li's margins. Maybe you've set a lateral margin for the li's, and you don't want the last in the row to have this margin. In that case, you can set its margin to 0 with li:nth-child(x) -> x is the number of li's in a row.